# How to pass value through RxJs chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

This should be an easy solution but I cannot seem to put it together...

I have a function that returns a Promise and another one that returns Promise. I need to call the latter using the former's return value but I also need both values at the end of the transformation chain. I have read some documentation about mergeMap and forkJoin but I cannot seem to use them to get the result I need:

```
function getBlob(id: string): Promise<Blob>;
function blobToBase64(imageBlob: Blob): Promise<string>;

// ...


// This is what I tried but I getting Observables back after the forkJoin instead of the actual values
return Observable.fromPromise(getBlob(id))
  .map((blob) => return Observable.forkJoin([Observable.of(blob), Observable.fromPromise(blobToBase64)])
  // data[0] and data[1] are undefined but it looks like data is actually an Observable from forkJoin.
  .map((data) => console.log(`Here is ${data[0]} and ${data[1]}`);
```

Can anyone explain how to wind up with both the blob and the base64 value at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create the `blobToBase64` promise based on the result of the first promise, you can use an operator from the [`flatMap`](https://namitamalik.github.io/Map-vs-FlatMap/) familly (`mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`, etc.)

The simplest is [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html), it take an observable, and when it emits, it create a new observable based on the emitted value.

```
return Observable.fromPromise(getBlob(id))
    .mergeMap((blob) => {

        // Create inner observable based on the blob
        return Observable.fromPromise(blobToBase64(blob))

            // Map the inner result to keep the blob variable
            .map((base64) => {
                return {base64, blob};
            })
    }).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result.blob, result.base64);
    });
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that but couldn't get it to work.. probably nested the mergeMap incorrectly or something.
Oh well, your answer definitely DOES work and provides the data that I need at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer, you can make it even better updating with new pipe collector for rxjs/operators:

return Observable.fromPromise(blobToBase64(blob))
            .pipe(
                // Map the inner result to keep the blob variable
                map((base64) => {
                return {base64, blob};
            })

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626960/how-to-combine-this-two-sevice-call-with-in-the-single-effect-one-out-put-result can you help this ?