# How to combine this two sevice call with in the single effect one out put result as input of other?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

This is my original effect. It loads data from a service call.

```
   getReviewEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(INIT),
    mergeMap(({ Id  }) => this.ReviewService.findByP(Id, new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() -30)),
      new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 30)), 'Approval')
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(reviews => {
          return [ReviewLoadSuccess({ drugReviews: getReviews(reviews) })
          ];
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(ReviewLoadFailure({ error: error }));
        })
      )
    )));
```

But the id, I take form this service call in loading.

```
this.ocService.getActiveoc().subscribe((oc => {
  this.Id = oc.id;
}));
```

I need to put the above code also, inside my effect and initial load it.need some expert help to do that. And also need to better way to given a date in 30 in the future and past.

--------------updated ------------------------------

I try to do it, like below but it was compiled error. need some expert help to resolve it,

```
getReviewEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(INIT),
    mergeMap((Id)=> this.socService.getActiveoc().toPromise().thenoc=>{return oc.id})
    .then(((Id)=>{
      this.drugReviewService.findBy(Id, new Date(),
      new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)), 'Approval')
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(reviews => {
          return ReviewLoadSuccess({ Reviews: getReviews(reviews) })
          ];
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(ReviewLoadFailure({ error: error }));
        })
      )
    })
    )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a `Promise()`

```
this.ocService.getActiveoc().toPromise()
   .then(res => {this.Id = res['id']})
   .then(() => { 
      getReviewEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(INIT),
      mergeMap(({ Id  }) => this.ReviewService.findByP(Id, new Date(new                       
      Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() -30)),
      new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 30)), 'Approval')
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(reviews => {
          return [ReviewLoadSuccess({ drugReviews: getReviews(reviews) })
          ];
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(ReviewLoadFailure({ error: error }));
        })
      )
    )));
 })
```

Comment: are there any way to put that id, take method inside the effect.. now , i create method and call it through effect ? (actually I need put that id, inside this method ' getReviewEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe('

Comment: Your could but you will have to wait with a promise or a setTimeout anyways

Comment: yes . i am abosulut beginer , as i feel I should wait for value avalable in ocService. can you please , update like that.

Comment: Rigth now your best option is keep it that way so its more easy to read for future changes, and every function should do one and only one task.

Comment: i try otheir way , but it given compile error..can you help me resolve it.